# UITextField value disappearing and reappearing in other UITableViewCells upon scrolling

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"inventoryItem";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];

}



UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

name.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",inventoryItems[indexPath.row][@"Inventory_Name"]];

NSLog(@"%@", name.text);



cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
return cell;

}
```

I am a beginner in Objective-C. I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a name and a `UITextField`. The `UITextField` tag is 4. Everytime I scroll, the values in the `UITextField`s disappear and appear in different cells. I understand, that this is because of the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, where cells get reused. I have researched a bit and have found that storing the `UITextField`s in an array and having them reloaded in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` might be the best way, but I am having trouble implementing that. An example would be ideal, or an easy way to get around this. Thank you.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Every time your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is called, you're setting your `name` UILabel.

I'm wondering/thinking that the value from `inventoryItems[indexPath.row][@"Inventory_Name"]` isn't what you are expecting?

Instead of doing:

```
NSLog(@"%@", name.text);
```

Try doing:

```
NSLog(@"%@ SHOULD EQUAL %@", inventoryItems[indexPath.row][@"Inventory_Name"], name.text);
```

And see if they always match?  I suspect you have some "`<null>`" values hiding in there.

Comment: FYI - this is a reposted question. I just closed it. You may want to post your answer on the dupe.